# I can't get the python commandline program to work. In spite of having set the PATH variable

Tags: python, installation

Quick question regarding the installation of python. I've installed Python 3.7.7 using the Windows 64 bit installer. I also had the installer update the PATH variable for me.
But when doing a quick check with the command-line using the command: "python --version", I'm getting nothing.
Nothing. No error, just an endline.

[User Path variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0EdV.png) [System Path variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j3lr.png) [command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtjVN.png)

Edit(1):

By going to the directory with python.exe within the terminal using the command "cd C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\" and then using python --version. The command works. I'm receiving the python version 3.7.7 message.
In spite of the path variable pointing to the same folder though, the command still doesn't work when I'm outside it.

A very weird thing I realized is that the command "py" does have some output. Regardless of what directory I'm in.[pyOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpV2d.png)
So that command works, while python --version doesn't. In spite of python --version working when I'm within the actual directory of python.exe.
I would assume that while I'm outside the python directory, there's some other executable that the system is accessing first? Regardless, I need all the functionality of python to work as I'm trying to get an external program to work with it and within that program, I'm getting the error that python is not installed. "Download python and add it to the path variable" it still says...

Edit(2)(SOLVED!):

There must've been some other folder within the path that had a python command that was overriding this one, as now it works and all I changed was the position of the folder within the path variable. It previously sat lowest, now it is the first one. And the command always works as intended, regardless of what directory I'm in.[previous position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wna9F.png) [new position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1GEc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, be sure you added the path to environment variable correctly

for testing, you can open your terminal in your path that you added to the environment variable and run `python --version` again.

If that not work for you try these solutions:
Close your terminal and open it again
or 
try `python3 --version` instead of `python --version`

Comment: I did what you asked and here are the results:
doing "cd C:\Users\Andrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\" in the command line. And then: "python --version" works every time. I got that path by copy-pasting it from my path variable. Also went to that folder with file explorer. And python.exe is definitely within that folder. So the path must be correct.
Maybe my assignment of it to the path variable is incorrect. I don't see how though ...

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you don't have Python installed through the Microsoft Store. You need to write "python" in the cmd and then a Microsoft Store window will pop up and let you download it.